# Can Spring ACL be integrated with Spring's WebSocket/STOMP for securing destinations?

Tags: spring, spring-security, stomp, spring-websocket

Is it possible to integrate Spring ACL (Domain Object Security) with Spring's WebSocket/STOMP support?

While I suppose that method security will work as expected, I'm interested whether it is possible to restrict WebSocket clients from subscribing (`SUBSCRIBE`) to a specific destination based on their access to a particular resource.

In the chat application I'm developing, there's a destination formatted as `/topic/rooms/${roomId}/messages`. My goal is to prevent clients from subscribing to this topic unless they have the necessary permissions to access the corresponding room.

[Domain Object Security (ACLs)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/acls.html)

I've reviewed the official Spring documentation and found no mention of how to integrate Spring ACL with Spring's WebSocket/STOMP for destination subscription security.